# Do accidents have any long-term consquences?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I'm not the best truck driver in the world. I'll usually crash into a couple things on a mission, resulting in the truck I'm driving taking damage. I've only done Quick Jobs so far, so any damage done to the truck is just taken off my fee for driving the truck. However, are there any other consequences to crashing into things, which go beyond the scope of my mission? Such as not being able to take on certain jobs due to having a high crash rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crashing only reduces current delivery payout. There are no penalties for your crash rate in the long term as they don't govern any other outcome in the game except the current payout. You are paid based on your performance on that delivery. There are no penalties applied based on your driver's historical crash rate. Only for the current delivery.

All the missions/deliveries that are available are dependent on the licenses and skills that the driver possesses and nothing else. The main skills that are needed are the permits that unlock delivery types. Those are:

- Liquid/Hazchem licenses
- Fragile Delivery Unlock
- High Value Cargo Unlock
- The Major and Urgent Delivery Unlock
- Long Distance Delivery Skill(Maxed if you want to see all routes)

So if you possess all the licenses and skills required by a delivery you will unlock that delivery mission.

So there are no possible downsides for you crashing, in the long term. It will only give a lesser payout for the current delivery, which might slow down progress a little. Apart from that only your driver skills matter in the long term.

Even the professional bonus in the payout is calculated based on the Driver level.

Comment: If it happens an accident with some of these special kinds of cargo, is there the possibility to die or get injured?